# Catching undefined value accessing in Perl

Tags: perl, member-variables

How can I catch access to member variables?

```
$Class1->{Class2}
```

If the `Class2` field doesn't exist, is is possible to catch this from an internal function?

Comment: You shouldn't go to the internals. Define accessor methods instead. The internal implementation of your objects can change. Go with a defined API instead. Also, this is an object, not a class.

Comment: You can prevent keys from being added, but that doesn't prevent from reading from non-existent keys. As you hinted, this does return `undef`, which should lead to an error down the line if you were expecting a value.

Comment: You could make your object array-based instead of hash-based to make it harder to use incorrectly (at least unintentionally). There are other tricks as well, but at some point, you just have say: "If you don't use the accessors we've provided, it's your own fault if you get bitten!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by providing proper getter/setter methods that wrap around your class/instance variables. The internals should never be accessed directly, particularly from outside of the class itself (it's wise to not do so within the class either, except for the actual method that maintains that specific attribute. Here's a very basic example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package A;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;

    $self->x($args{x});
    $self->y($args{y});

    return $self;
}
sub x {
    my ($self, $x) = @_;
    $self->{x} = $x if defined $x;
    return $self->{x} // 1;
}
sub y {
    my ($self, $y) = @_;
    $self->{y} = $y if defined $y;
    return $self->{y} // 2;
}

package main;

my $obj = A->new(x => 5, y => 3);

print $obj->x ."\n";
print $obj->y ."\n";
```

Now, you could just as easily do `print $obj->{x}`, but that's where your problem is. What happens when the code is much more complicated than this, and for some reason you want to change the `x` attribute name to `foo`, but retain the `x()` method? `$obj->{x}` will now be `undef` as its never set.

Always use the provided methods for accessing attributes of a class/object. Encapsulation such as this is a staple of OO programming.

Comment: DRY -- unless you're getting paid by the amount of lines wasted on writing accessors.

Comment: The principle is fine, but those accessors fail very poorly when the caller tries to set the value to undef (intentionally or not). You should check the number of args provided (`my $self = shift; $self->{x} = shift if @_; return $self->{x};`) and *add* checks and conversions to that if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you probably shouldn't. The problem here is - if you access a variable within a class directly... then you just can. You can prevent this with a couple of workarounds - and this is where things like Moose come in.

And there's a couple of slightly hacky tricks like inside-out objects (which I think aren't common practice any more - Perl Best Practice advocated them some years back) or using anonymous hashes to hold state.

But failing that - why not use an accessor, and auto-generate one using 'AUTOLOAD'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings; 

use vars '$AUTOLOAD';
sub AUTOLOAD { 
   my ( $self ) = @_; 

   my $subname = $AUTOLOAD =~ s/.*:://r;

   if ( $self -> {$subname} ) { 
      return $self -> {$subname}; 
   }
   warn "Sub called $subname was called\n";
   return "$subname"; 
}

sub new {
   my ( $class ) = @_;
   my $self = {};
   bless $self, $class;
}

package main; 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $object = MyClass -> new; 
$object -> {var} = "fleeg";

print "Undef fiddle was: ", $object -> fiddle,"\n";
print "But 'var' was: ", $object -> var,"\n";
```

This has the same problem, in that changing method names might cause things to break. However it has the advantage that you can handle 'invalid' method calls however you like.

But really - explicit 'get' and 'set' methods are better choices for most use-cases.

Comment: `AUTOLOAD` would be the last thing I would recommend for this.  Generating accessors for a well-defined list takes no more code and is much more robust. Beyond that, there `Object::Accessor`, `Class::Accessor::*`, `Moo(se)?` etc.

Comment: A good primer on inside-out objects is at http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2006-03-31.html and while there are now many modules to do it and more, I think it explains the concept really well.